# Does Resurrection have a clear end?

Tags: plot-explanation, resurrection

I don't want to start watching the series "Resurrection" if it has no clear plot direction or conclusion. I've been burned by the likes of "Lost" and I don't want to go through that again.

[image: Resurrection]

Is Resurrection written with an end or explanation, or is it just made up as it goes? (I understand this may be difficult to answer, so I'll clarify)

---

Update:
According to the IMBD page the series is based on a novel or series of novels. Do the novels have a clear direction? And does the series align with the novels enough to assume the end in the novels will be the end in the TV series?

It also says the series is an adaptation of the series "The Returned", did that have a clear conclusion?

Related: [Continuity errors or another Lost?](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2647586/board/nest/227568662?ref_=tt_bd_1)

Comment: You know we're only three episodes into an eight episode season, right? It's really hard to answer this given that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because no one knows the answer yet, leading to either just "no one knows" or pure speculative answers.

Comment: @Tom: I tried an answer, but agree totally. Might be worth having this type of off topic question made more explicit in the Help Center.

Comment: @Tom ... I actually believe there is a valid question in that, *Is there anything written which shows the end goal of the series?* Meaning, has anyone in the production team (as a whole) putout anything saying, *Is this a five year mission?* or some such ...

Comment: @Paulster2 - Even if the producers/writers had an idea on how to end it, the show can still get canceled before we get to see it. - I don't understand the mention of __Lost__, it had a "proper" conclusion.

Comment: @Oliver_C ... But we are talking about the intent of the show, not trying to look into the future to see what might be. If there is some information out there stating what their plan is, that is what the OP is asking about (IMHO). -- I agree about **Lost** ... I also thought it had a plan and a conclusion. Some may not have liked how it went about it, but JJ Abrams is the man :P

Comment: @Paulster2 - Yes, but how is a vague _"We have a plan"_ from the producers helpful? The people behind __Lost__ also had a "plan" and the OP was `burned` anyway.

Comment: @Oliver_C ... If the "*We have a plan*" were elaborated upon, it might be very helpful. I can, however, see how this type of information would become dated very quickly, and in that context might be off topic.

Comment: I think all the comments above are correct. If this question were left open, I'd need to favourite my answer and come back and update it in a few years once the series ended.

Comment: Where is it stated in the help center, or on Meta that questions that have an answer of 'we don't know yet' are off-topic?!

Comment: @Keen It doesn't outright say that this is off-topic, but it does say "A title's release date or rumors about a specific title or series." And while this isn't specifically a question about rumors, the answers will be the same. Which is either "we don't know yet" or something purely speculative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're only three episodes into the eight episode season, so currently it's impossible to say.

[This link](http://familyloveandotherstuff.com/resurrection-abc/) contains an interview with the show's Executive Producers Tara Butters (@breadandbutters) and Michele Fazekas and thus contains major spoilers. **Therefore, you probably shouldn't open it!!** However, to give a summary of what's inside it.

**Pros**:  The creators appear to have *some* idea of where they are going. They are trying to create a long, slow-unfolding mythology.

**Cons**: The last question from the interview:

> **Q: Was LOST an influence?**
>
> **Tara**: Absolutely. I don’t think you can do a
> show like this without having some influence. I feel very strongly
> that this show shouldn’t be more than 13 episodes a season, because my
> favorite seasons of LOST were the shorter seasons because they could
> be so much more.
>
> **Michele**: When you’re building these continuous storyline
> episodes, you can’t jump around, you have to sort of build them in
> order. And if you change something back here, it sort of affects this.
> So that’s why we really liked having a smaller number of episodes, so
> you can really craft it and be smart about it. Versus just kind of
> filling space.

Given you *specifically* mentioned being disappointed by **Lost** in your question, maybe its influence is a bad sign!

At the very least, I would point out that if you're looking to get really sucked into a fun and engrossing series with a clear end, you should probably stick to one that has been out a while or completed its runtime!

Comment: _Tara Butters_ and _Michele Fazekas_ previously created [Reaper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaper_(TV_series)), which was canceled after the second season. They were however kind enough [to later reveal](http://cliqueclack.com/tv/2010/02/01/how-reaper-would-have-ended-straight-from-the-creators/2/) some of the answers that were left open.

Answer (score 0):

No one knows, yet. The show just started its first season, so we have no idea of its over-arching structure.  Check in after at least the first season has completed.

Comment: Maybe more fit as a comment rather than an answer?

Comment: 'No one knows' is a perfectly cromulent answer. I'll edit it with updated information once it's available.